# Finding out if browser changed routes in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

Hey so I am currently using browserHistory.goForward() and browserHistory.goBack() to move forward and backwards using arrows in my app, however I need to be able to see if the route actually changed (browserHistory.goForward/goBack() actually executed) or if the history ends and therefore the route did not change. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that, you can check your browserHistory listen event.

```
import {browserHistory } from 'react-router'

browserHistory.listen((e) =>{
    switch(e.action){
        case "PUSH":
            console.log("History has changed - FORWARD");
            break;
        case "POP":
            console.log("History has changed - BACK");
            break;
        case "REPLACE":
            console.log("History has not changed");
            break;
    }
})
```